# Double Title Bar in Android Studio Design View

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

So I hadn't updated this project in a while and found that all my xml views seem to be showing double title bars when previewing my layout.

Here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout_register"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="false">
<RelativeLayout> Content here </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"
        android:background="#fff">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer_register"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:divider="#eee"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any thoughts? Is this causing my layouts to be off? Because it seems "centering" isn't putting things in the center at all now.

Here's toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/toolbar_red"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:theme="@style/myAppTheme">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: 1. Its called ActionBar.
2. Trying removing `<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />`

Comment: it is coming because you have chosen, API 22 for layout preview make is API 21 and it will disappear. well you sure updated your Android studio, i have to tell you that